# Pause a test 2 mins on every 1000 users reached in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

We are running 25k users for load test.

Dev team asks to wait atleast 2 mins on every 1000 users boarded.. Is it possible by IfController by taking count of modules by 1000 and make it pause for 2 mins..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) and set Delay of 2 minutes by separating every 10 K to a row with Initial delay

> separate ramp-up time, shutdown time, flight time for each shedule record

Example:

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I wanted